# IOS UItextfield chinese character will disappear.

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

When i open the editing page, it able to show the Chinese character, but when I tried to input the Chinese character it dint input into the UItextfield.

Anyone face this problems before ?? any solution ?

I tried using UIKeyboardDefault also can't.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this problem, and I fixed it by following step.

1. set the textField borderStyle to non-UITextBorderStyleNone(such as UITextBorderStyleLine) in storyboard or xib;
2. reset borderStyle to UITextBorderStyleNone in -viewDidLoad.

Hope this helps.